# Minecraft Crashes on Startup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have tried reinstalling already. I also have allocated 7000MB of ram. It is also running fine on version 1.12

Here is my error log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jnCXdDt89H/

Comment: Oh, interesting edit. 1.12 works fine with the same settings that crash on 1.14.2? That might either be caused my 1.14 actually using more memory (when 1.12 was released, the system requirements were 2GB RAM) or it could be a bug. There's a lot of information in these two reports, does anything from there help you? https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-23484 https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-6550

Comment: Oh yeah, the malware cleaner on the second link worked for me. Turns out I had some malware from a sketchy auto clicker I downloaded. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's a different solution (cleaning adware), though, than the other thread suggests. I added the link from Fabian's comment, but am not sure if this is sufficient.

Comment: @Joachim There's nothing distinct about the questions. The fact that they both have different useful answers suggests they should be merged by a moderator, rather than one left open..

Comment: @pppery That seems to be the optimal solution, yes.

Answer (score 1):

4 GB of RAM are the minimum hardware requirement of Minecraft: https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-java-edition-system-requirements ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190619193439/https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-java-edition-system-requirements)). The error you got was caused by not enough memory.

Comment: Oops sorry I meant I allocated 7000MB, or 7 GB

Comment: Do you actually **have** 7GB of RAM?

Comment: Yes I have 8. The result does not change whether I allocate 2, 4, 7, or 8

Comment: Maybe the other programs on your computer need more than 1GB of RAM. Try assigning 5GB instead.

Comment: Just tried that and no luck. I really think that changing memory allocation won't fix it because like I said I have already tried it many different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Many different things can cause this error code, including malware. More information…

- here: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-23484
- and here: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-6550